# Pin results in solr

Tags: solr

Is there a way to render first 10 results in particular order when q=* in Solr.

I have tried below methods but each one has some road blocks. 
1. Boosting those results, it is inconsistent.
2. Hard code the results in front end and removing those from solr results. But we have facet feature, which need to show the facets for these pinned result also.

Please let me know if any other ways to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

you have [query elevation feature](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Query+Elevation+Component) for this. You typically use this with specific terms as search input, like:

- q:ipod --> elevate doc1, doc2
- q:tv   --> elevate doc3, doc4

but maybe it works too with the *:* case, just try. If if does not work, you could just replace *:* with a special query value 'q:ELEVATEDQ' in the front end and use that special term in the elevate file instead. That should work for sure.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. But i believe this wont work in this scenario. For example, instead of q=*, am giving q=auto.. in that field, i am replacing  auto with * using patterntokenizer, then only it will render the required results. After this search, elevation will applied, so in this case it will * only. So it wont work as per requriement